# Why delegate method shows no input value?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I'm trying to understand why this delegate method has no value in the output. I thought it had to be:
Value is - 5
Value is - 5

But the result is:
Value is -
Value is -

Why number "5" is absent is this example?

```
    class Program
{
    internal delegate void Feedback(Int32 value);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Feedback fbChain = null;
        Feedback delFeedback = new Feedback(Print);

        fbChain += delFeedback;
        fbChain += delFeedback;

        fbChain.Invoke(5);
    }

    internal static void Print(Int32 value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value is - ", value);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
internal static void Print(Int32 value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value is - {0}", value);
}
```

(You left out the `{0}`, which is what tells `Console.WriteLine` to insert the second parameter into the output.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try these:

```
    internal static void Print(Int32 value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value is - " + value);
}
```

or

```
internal static void Print(Int32 value)
{

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value is - {0}", value));
}
```